# How to handle dataset which is a csv file that contains image names in one column and image path in other column?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, dataset

I am new to python and machine learning. I am just practicing with model training and dataset thingy. I came across this dataset that have test and train folder. In that folder there are several containing different images (It's a music instrument dataset so each music instrument is categorized by names in different folders). And the csv file has this name of the instrument and their path in the folder like this: [Instrument.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wykkf.png)

Now my question is how do I handle this dataset? Should I iterate through train and test folders or use this csv file?
And if I want to choose the folder option then how can go through each sub-folder and access the images?
Here is the link for the dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/gpiosenka/musical-instruments-image-classification

sorry if the question doesn't make any sense or too easy to do it. I agree I am noob

Answer (score 0):

You should read the csv file into a pandas dataframe to create your dataset. Alternatively, you can also iterate through the directories using `os.listdir()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: Hi thx for the reply. I did try this method before but I am stuck at the part where I have to iterate through images and you know train the model... This might sound confusing to you. I've never worked on this kind of dataset before

Comment: @MalharKhairnar https://www.kaggle.com/code/gpiosenka/use-csv-file-to-make-data-sets This could be a good starting place for you.

Comment: Hey thx again. I got the solution for it. I just have to use this command tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator to generate the images from sub folders and thats it. Thx for your help